# How can I use Powershell to replace a single file in all instances of Azure Cloud Service

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cloud-services

I'm looking for a quick way to patch/replace a file in Azure Cloud Service production instances. Deploying to Azure is faster than ever, but still takes about 12 minutes from our CI/Build process. We recently had a fire drill which caused us to manually RDP into each instance an manually update a text file.

I have searched and only seem to find people wanting to change *.configs at deployment where it's better to do this at Build time, or even dynamic in OnStart job. I'm wanting to modify a file after it's already in production.

Ideally, there is something like a script.ps1 that runs, and has a sourcefile and deploymentPath passed into it that just works.

Something like ....

```
script.ps1 -SourceFile file.txt -DeploymentPath "E:\approot\config\file.txt"
```

Thank you for any ideas, pointers, links, help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WinRM.

Note that you're going to have to open port 5985 on your cloud service instance to reach the WinRM listener. This can be done in the ServiceDefinition.csdef.template with something like:

`<InputEndpoint name="WinRM" protocol="tcp" port="5985" />`

Also make sure that the WinRM listener is started (over HTTP if using 5985, HTTPS uses 5986).

If you are sending a patching a small file, then you can send it directly as a parameter to a remote powershell command (your session is connected to the instance that you would like to patch):

```
$f ="filename"
$c = Get-Content $f
invoke-command -session $s -script {param($filename,$contents) `
     set-content -path $filename -value $contents} -argumentlist $f,$c
```

If you are sending a bigger file, then you would want to chunk it.See this example: http://poshcode.org/2216